# Python Plotly: make secondary axis log scale

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataset x,y1,y2. Using Plotly, I want to:

- Plot y1 on axis 1: linear
- Plot y2 on axis2: log

I imagine it would look somehting like this:

```py
fig.update_layout( yaxis_type="log", secondary_y=True) #A command like this one
```

This is my setup so far

```py
import pandas as pd

import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df= pd.DataFrame({'x': [0,1,2,3,4], 'y1' : [2,4,6,8,10], 'y2': [5,10,20,30,35]})

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y1"], name='normal scale'),
    secondary_y=False
)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y2"], name='make this log scale'),
    secondary_y=True,
)
fig.update_layout( yaxis_type="log", secondary_y=True) #A command like this one
fig.show()
```

Comment: An error occurred for `secondary_y=True`, so it was removed and the graph is now displayed. The left y-axis is in log format and the right y-axis is in normal format. What is the challenge now?

Comment: @r-beginners I would like axis 2 to be log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the other y-axis and set up a 'log' for it. I used this [information](https://community.plotly.com/t/subplots-with-logscale-and-two-y-axes/19520) as a reference.

```
import pandas as pd

import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df= pd.DataFrame({'x': [0,1,2,3,4], 'y1' : [2,4,6,8,10], 'y2': [5,10,20,30,35]})

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y1"], name='normal scale'),
    secondary_y=False
)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y2"], name='make this log scale', yaxis='y2'), # update
    secondary_y=True,
)
fig.update_layout(
                     yaxis2=dict(type='log')
                     ) # update
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In your example both scales are log, i am looking for only yaxis2 to be log (numbers start far apart and get closer as you move up)

Comment: It works if you remove yaxis_type="log", and just leave ; fig.update_layout(                    yaxis2=dict(type='log')                     )

Comment: That way, only the right-hand Y-axis is 'log' and the left-hand Y-axis is normal. In your question, the right side is normal and the left side is not 'log'?

Comment: Isn't the question y1 linear and y2 logarithmic? If `yaxis1=dict(type='log')`, then y1 is logarithmic and y2 is linear, and The following is a list of all of the products Feel free to edit it.

Comment: Now i understand what you meant. The data is just random. I want y1 linear, y2 log. my first 2 comments are correct. it works with fig.update_layout( yaxis2=dict(type='log') ).
Do you know also how i can set the ticks for y1,y2 to be the same (something like make yticks1=yticks2 )

Comment: and just leave yaxis1=dict(type='log') ?